# Compile winapi with cygwin

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, cygwin

I have tried compiling a windows executable using the win32api, however I have encountered many road blocks.

First thing to try was `gcc -mno-cygwin [...]` which results in `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'` which is strange since `man gcc|grep -e '-mno-cygwin'` is successful and mingw is installed.

No matter what other header files I try to include I always end up with unsatisfied circular include dependencies (a.h requires b.h requires a.h).  What set of header files are required to properly compile an executable based on the win32 api?

header files I have tried:

- w32api/winnt.h
- w32api/ddk/ntddk.h
- w32api/Windows.h
- w32api/ntdef.h

source code:

```
$ cat source.c
#include <w32api/winnt.h>
#include <w32api/ddk/ntddk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  PHANDLE hProcess;
  CLIENT_ID processId;
  processId.UniqueProcess = (HANDLE) 1000;
  processId.UniqueThread = 0;

  NtOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_VM_WRITE, 0, &processId);
  return 0;
}

$ gcc -o a.exe -I/usr/include/w32api -I/usr/include/w32api/ddk source.c
In file included from memoryEdit.c:1:0:
/usr/include/w32api/winnt.h:291:11: error: unknown type name 'CONST'
   typedef CONST WCHAR *LPCWCH,*PCWCH;
           ^
[...]

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.4.0
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 HOST_NAME 2.5.2(0.297/5/3) 2016-06-23 14:29 x86_64 Cygwin
```

Comment: *"Windows.h"* for standard Windows applications. However, [NtOpenProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567022.aspx) isn't part of the Windows API. You'll have to include *Ntddk.h* or *Ntifs.h*, and work out the rest. Any reason you aren't using the Windows API call [OpenProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) like everyone else?

Comment: @IInspectable since `Ntifs.h` can't be found anywhere on my system I'll assume you meant `ddk/ntifs.h`, either way that results in the error `/usr/x86_64-w64-=mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/ddk/Ntifs.h:32:19: fatal error: ntddk.h: No such file or directory` which just leaves me with my original question.  As for using `NtOpenProcess` I couldn't care less, I just copy and pasted a hello world style example program, and expected it to at least compile.

Comment: @IInspectable I added `-I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/ddk` to the gcc command and it was able to find `ddk/ntifs.h`, either way that results in the error `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/ddk/wdm.h:376:1: error: redefinition of '_InterlockedAdd64'` from the `Windows.h` include but if I remove that then I am left with `error: unknown type name 'BYTE'` which just leaves me with my original question.

Comment: *"As for using `NtOpenProcess` I couldn't care less"* - Well, you should. `NtOpenProcess` isn't part of the Windows API, and since you tagged your question as such, you owe us an explanation, why you chose to go with the (mostly undocumented and unsupported) native API. Had you picked `OpenProcess` (which **is** part of the Windows API) it indeed would *"at least compile"*. So why are you programming against an unsupported interface?

Comment: @IInspectable So a windows function for the windows os is not considered part of the api ... *for windows*... I do not know much about windows programming, since I almost always program for linux/unix, but this sounds fairly strange.  Please explain *yourself* how is a function that is part of windows not part of the windows api, even when it is documented on microsoft's own website as being part of their api?

Comment: @IInspectable why do I OWE you an explanation, I already explained that I copied it from a hello world program.

Comment: The Windows API is the API surface that the Win32 subsystem exposes. It is a stable, documented, and supported interface. `NtOpenProcess` isn't part of that API. It is part of the [Native API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_API), that's largely undocumented and unsupported. If you're using that API, you shouldn't use the [tag:winapi] tag. Since Linux doesn't have anything like a supported API, this may be harder to understand for you, even when you know the effects: Trying to run a 10-year old binary on Linux is almost certainly going to fail. Doing the same on Windows usually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc -mno-cygwin` has been removed ages ago.

If you want to compile a windows program you need to use not the gcc compiler, that is cygwin to cygwin, but the cross compilers cygwin to windows.
There are 2 package variants depending on the arch:

mingw64-i686-gcc
mingw64-x86_64-gcc

Answer (score 0):

I had no troubles just now with a compilation in Eclipse/gcc.  Here's my testfile:

```
/*

============================================================================
 Name        : win32gcctest.c
 Author      : Clark Thomborson
 Version     : 1.0
 Copyright   : Copyleft 
 Description : Testing winapi synchronous file access within Cygwin
============================================================================
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fileapi.h>

void my_write(char* fname) {
    HANDLE hFile;
    char DataBuffer[] = "This is some test data to write to the file.";
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD) strlen(DataBuffer);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;

    hFile = CreateFile(fname,        // name of the write
            GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
            0,                      // do not share
            NULL,                   // default security
            CREATE_ALWAYS,          // overwrite any existing file
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
            NULL);                  // no attr. template

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        DWORD last_err = GetLastError();
        printf("Error code %d: unable to open file \"%s\" for write.\n", last_err, fname);
        exit( last_err );
    }

    printf("Writing %d bytes to %s.\n", dwBytesToWrite, fname);

    bErrorFlag = WriteFile(hFile,
            DataBuffer,      // start of data to write
            dwBytesToWrite,  // number of bytes to write
            &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
            NULL);            // no overlapped structure

    if (FALSE == bErrorFlag) {
        DWORD last_err = GetLastError();
        printf("Error code %d: unable to write to file \"%s\".\n", last_err, fname);
        exit( GetLastError() );
        exit( last_err );
    } else {
        if (dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite) {
            // This is an error because a synchronous write that results in
            // success (WriteFile returns TRUE) should write all data as
            // requested. This would not necessarily be the case for
            // asynchronous writes.
            printf("Error: dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        } else {
            printf("Wrote %d bytes to %s successfully.\n", dwBytesWritten, fname);
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}

HANDLE my_open_for_read(char* fname) {
    HANDLE hFile;

    hFile = CreateFile(
        fname,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_DELETE, // another process may delete this file while this handle is open
        NULL, // no security attributes
        OPEN_EXISTING, // returns error if file not found
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, // no special attributes, so can't do async IO
        NULL // no attributes will be copied from another file
        );
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        DWORD last_err = GetLastError();
        printf("Error code %d: unable to open file \"%s\" for read.\n", last_err, fname);
        exit( last_err );
    }

    return hFile;
}

ssize_t my_read(HANDLE hFile, void *buffer, size_t bytes_to_read) {

    DWORD bytes_read;

    if (ReadFile(hFile, buffer, bytes_to_read, &bytes_read, NULL)) {
        return (ssize_t) bytes_read;
    } else {
        DWORD last_err = GetLastError();
        printf("Error code %d: unable to read file.\n", last_err );
        exit( last_err );
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char fname[32] = "test.txt";

    my_write( fname );

    printf("Reading %s.\n", fname);

    char buff[1024];
    HANDLE hFile = my_open_for_read( fname );
    ssize_t nc = my_read( hFile, buff, 1023 ); // allow room for terminating byte
    if( nc >= 0 ) {
        buff[nc] = 0; // terminate string
        printf("Read %d characters: %s", (int) nc, buff);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } else { // buggy my_read()
        printf("Error %d", (int) nc );
        return nc;
    }
}
```